# Windows Service doesn't execute OnStart()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I'm having a problem with a really simple Windows service. I've created the service like explained in the [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I have:

- the service which should create a simple file in c:\mylogs
- a serviceinstaller (serviceprocessinstaller runs as LocalSystem)
- a setup project to install the service

I can start and stop the service via `net start/stop <servicename>`. But nothing happens, even if I perform actions in the constructor of the service.

I install, start and stop the service as localadmin.

Comment: Check the eventlog, maybe your service can't start due to an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service initialisation code should go in the OnStart event handler, not the constructor. Your service cleanup and shutdown code should go in the OnStop event.

All you should really do in the start event is fire up a worker thread that will run as long as your service is active and do the actual processing. You can use a BackgroundWorker component to simplify this. When the service is stopped you do any necessary cleanup, and terminate the background thread.

Code in the OnStart and OnStop event handlers should not take longer than a second or two to run - the Windows Service Manager is waiting for the service to report whether it has successfully started or stopped, and you will see an error if your service doesn't quickly give feedback to the Service Control Manager.

Comment: Finally i found out, that i was working with the wrong installer file. VS2010 didn't build the setup project when choosing "rebuild solution". So it was an version with no functionality. Shame on me :|

Comment: Oh dear. These things happen. At least you solved the problem! I remember my first attempts at writing services many years ago in Borland C++ Builder. Not good.