# Windows service onStart() isn't executing

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that is having trouble executing the Onstart() method after installing it and running it from the service menu.I'm logging everything that is happening at every step of the execution to see where the problem is. But there is no error, it logs and runs fine in the main method , up until the service is actually called to run and then it just does nothing.

It's interesting to note that it doesn't have ANY problem running in debug.

My program class(starting point) from which the service is called :

```
 public class Program
{
    private static Container _container;
    private static ILogger<Program> _logger;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    private static void Main()
    {
        _container = SimpleInjectorContainer.Build(registerConfig: true, useThreadScopedLifestyle: true);
        SimpleInjectorContainer.LoggAndVerify(_container);

        using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container))
        {
            try
            {
                _logger = _container.GetInstance<ILogger<Program>>();
                _logger.LogInformation("Test - Works");
                VerifyConfiguration();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = _container.GetInstance<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "Configuration is not valid");
                throw;
            }

            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                RunDebug();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
                _logger.LogInformation("It's Here 49");
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    _container.GetInstance<SenderService>()
                };
                _logger.LogInformation("It's Here 56");
                //up until here its fine, but it doesn't run the next line
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
                _logger.LogInformation("It's Here 58");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RunDebug()
    {
        var senderService = _container.GetInstance<SenderService>();
        senderService.TestStart();
        Console.WriteLine("Sender Started Debug");
        Console.ReadLine();
        senderService.TestStop();
    }
    private static void VerifyConfiguration()
    {
        var configValidator = _container.GetInstance<IConfigurationValidator>();
        configValidator.VerifyOperatorPrefixNumbers();
        configValidator.VerifyConfiguration();
        configValidator.VerifyOperators();

    }
}
```

My actual service :

```
public partial class SenderService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly Container container;
    private readonly ILogger<SenderService> logger;
    private readonly ISmsHandlerConfig config;
    private readonly IConfigurationValidator configValidator;

    public SenderService(
        Container container,
        ILogger<SenderService> logger,
        ISmsHandlerConfig config,
        IConfigurationValidator configValidator)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.container = container;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.config = config;
        this.configValidator = configValidator;
    }

    public void TestStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting {ServiceName} service");
        this.OnStart();
    }

    public void TestStop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stopping {ServiceName} service");
        this.OnStop();
    }

    protected void OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation($"{this.ServiceName} starting");
            SmsHandlerAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex, $"Error starting service {this.ServiceName}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Dispose();
            this.logger.LogInformation($"{this.ServiceName} stopped");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex, $"Error stopping service {this.ServiceName}");
        }
    }

    private void SmsHandlerAction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation($"{this.ServiceName} started");
            using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(this.container))
            {
                var smsSenderService = this.container.GetInstance<ISmsSenderService>();
                var sendResult = smsSenderService.SendSms(this.container);

                // Wait if there are not messages for sending
                if (!sendResult && this.config.IdleTimeMiliseconds != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(this.config.IdleTimeMiliseconds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is what is logged:

> 2019-02-12 18:02:18.7972 INFO Test - Works
>
> 2019-02-12 18:02:20.6370 INFO It's Here 49
>
> 2019-02-12 18:02:20.6410 INFO It's Here 56

and after I stop the service :

> 2019-02-12 18:02:35.7375 INFO SenderService stopped
>
> 2019-02-12 18:02:35.7375 INFO It's Here 58

It missing the `this.logger.LogInformation($"{this.ServiceName} starting");` part.

It doesn't log the line in the onstart method , because it never actually executes, I checked if the service was running, but just failed to log and that is not the case.

My IDE is VS 2017, OS is Win 7, DI library is SimpleInjector 4.0.12.

I know about a similar question asked on stackoverfllow([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027306/windows-service-doesnt-execute-onstart)) but I don't see how it solves my problem.

Also my event viewer doesn't log any problems also, only information about it starting successfully.

I'm pretty lost so any guidance will be of help.

Comment: What does your `ServiceInstaller` look like? Specifically, does the `ServiceName` of the installer match the `ServiceName` of your `ServiceBase` derived class?

Comment: It does match, both are names SenderService.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was because I removed the override on the OnStart().

Comment: So you're saying that you ignored the warning from the compiler? Before asking on SO, you really ought to make sure that you're code exhibits *zero* warnings (unless you're specifically asking about a particular warning)

Comment: It had no warning on build, I checked all the warning and it had zero. Maybe my ruleset was alter by some college I don't know.

Comment: It should be raising [CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108) without the `override` specified That's not a code analysis/ruleset warning. It's a compiler warning.

Comment: here is a screenshot , i have no idea then.
Edit: I cant format at all sorry  - https://imgur.com/RwzACDT